# Python output to command line; Error not defined

Tags: python, function, command-line, output

I am trying to write a script that takes one argument and writes the output to the command window. For some reason I am getting the error:

```
NameError: name 'month' not defined
```

Here is the entire script:

```
import sys


hex = str(sys.argv)
sys.stdout.write (month(hex) + " " + day(hex) + ", " + year(hex) + " " + hour(hex) + ":" + minute(hex) + ":" + second(hex))

def year (hex):
    year = int(hex[0:2], 16)
    year = year + 1970
    return str(year)

def month (hex):
    month = int(hex[2:4], 16)
    if month == 0:
        month = "January"
        return month
    elif month == 1:
        month = "February"
        return month
    elif month == 2:
        month = "March"
        return month
    elif month == 3:
        month = "April"
        return month
    elif month == 4:
        month = "May"
        return month
    elif month == 5:
        month = "June"
        return month
    elif month == 6:
        month = "July"
        return month
    elif month == 7:
        month = "August"
        return month
    elif month == 8:
        month = "September"
        return month
    elif month == 9:
        month = "October"
        return month
    elif month == 10:
        month = "November"
        return month
    else:
        month = "December"
        return month

def day (hex):
    day = int(hex[4:6], 16)
    return str(day)

def hour (hex):
    hour = int(hex[6:8], 16)
    if hour < 10:
        return "0" + str(hour)
    else:
        return str(hour)

def minute (hex):
    minute = int(hex[8:10], 16)
    if minute < 10:
        return "0" + str(minute)
    else:
        return str(minute)

def second (hex):
    second = int(hex[10:12], 16)
    if minute < 10:
        return "0" + str(second)
    else:
        return str(second)
```

When I used an online python interpreter to run it, the functions worked fine. I just don't know how to run it from the command line and send the output back to the command window. Thanks

Comment: do not use the same variable name as the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python a file is parsed line by line from top to bottom, so the functions `month`,`year`,`hour`,`minute` and `second` are not defined yet for this line:

```
sys.stdout.write (month(hex) + " " + day(hex) + ", " + year(hex) + " " + hour(hex) + ":" + minute(hex) + ":" + second(hex))
```

Move these function definitions above this line.

And using a local variable with same name as the function name is not a good idea.

As `sys.argv` returns a list (with first element being the filename), so you can't apply `hex` over it.  Apply `hex` on the items of the list, i.e `hex( int(sys.argv[1]) )`

```
>>> lis = ['foo.py', '12']
>>> hex( int(lis[1]) )    #use `int()` as hex expects a number
'0xc'
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the line `sys.stdout.write`... after your function definitions.

Please, don't use `month` for both your function and a variable inside this function.